# Security Reasons to upgrade from Windows XP Needed

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-xp, security

Is there a white paper, or any long winded sob story already written why we desperately need to stop using Windows XP and upgrade to... well, anything other than XP really, 7/8/10. ?

I've searched, and you would have though Microsoft would be spamming the internet with reasons to upgrade, but I've come up with nothing, was/is it really that loved?

anyway, I really do need some sound reasons to get rid (I personally want to get rid due because of the limited memory support, can't use latest .Net framework and can't use latest SQL Express, but if I had a sound security reason.. well people would panic into upgrading right?)

Comment: Why do you need justification. Who are you trying to convince?

Comment: Microsoft probably isn't pushing this very hard, as there's not many people still running such an old OS.

Comment: There is some serious cost in upgrading over 1000 computers... and unfortunately, 'something bad might happen in the future that we don't really know how bad it will be but it might just happen and then we're stuffed' just isn't cutting it... I've tried, they don't listen... :(

Comment: Be aware not all computers can run Windows 10. I have one running Windows 7 that can't be upgraded to 10 because the CPU isn't compatible.

Comment: That's quite shocking that a company with 1000 PC's would still be running a hopelessly outdated, unsupported OS.

Comment: There have been several recent news stories of major institutions suffering losses due to running outdated and insecure software (http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/04/22/healthcare_insecurity/) and as most major web browsers no longer support WinXP you will be making it easier to attack the machine by having an insecure browser with potentially insecure plugins running on an insecure machine.  That's not a combination I would want to see in any machine I connect to the Internet.

Comment: Most software companies have long since dropped support for XP. You won't be able to upgrade the security software, and the OS itself obviously is not secure. It's very irresponsible to run a company this way. Might be time for the CEO to be put out to pasture.

Comment: Note, it wasn't so much that XP was loved, but that Vista was hated especially in 2006. Once 2009 came around, everyone had been forced to upgrade their printers and video cards due to failures anyway,  the transition to Win7 was much less painful.

Comment: Just to add, yes we can discuss all day long that this should have been done, and as you quite rightly point out, there were some compatibility problems that never got resolved. Still to this day actually. but we need to force the issue... it would seem the answer to my question is no. Nothing official has been put forward as a reason. A white paper from some organisation would be ideal.

Comment: http://www.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/thanks/xp-compliance-wp.shtml

Answer (score -1):

I would point out things like UAC, VBS, Device guard and similiar advances in protecting system, other would be bugs that aren´t fixed anymore and are already abused by malware actors. Bitlocker availability, programs not supporting XP.

Those are few reasons i would point out. Staying on XP is almost like a ticking bomb waiting for ransomware to spread on network and cost you a lot more money.